# jboss using 9990 port instead of 9090

Tags: windows, jboss, windows-service

I am referring to the documentation [here](http://community.i2b2.org/wiki/display/getstarted/2.4.2.4+Run+JBoss+as+a+Windows+Service) and running JBoss as Windows as Service. I am not sure why it doesn't runs on `localhost:9090` as mentioned in the documentation but on `localhost:9990`. I don't see anything related to port 9990 in standalone.xml file. Also, the page I get is different as compared with the screenshot in the documentation:

[image]

Comment: John, what's the _actual_ question here?

Comment: @alexus Why it doesn't runs on port 9090 as mentioned in the documentation screenshot?

Comment: why? seems like documentation is a bit outdated, but feel free to reconfigure it to any port you like)

Comment: So you mean it should be 9990 only always and not 9090?

Comment: it doesn't really matter if it's 9990, 9090, 9443, 9999, 8009 etc

Comment: @alexus I don't really see the port 9990 listed any where in the `standalone.xml` for my jBoss. I am wondering how `localhost:9990` is letting me access the console for jBoss. When I try to use other ports, it doesn't work. Do you think I should be making an entry in the file for port 9990?